# Jquery element.prop("href") does not return absolute url

Tags: javascript, jquery, href, cheerio, prop

I need to get absolute urls of links in a given url.To achieve this I use jquery and cheerio with browserify on javascript however prop("href") returns relative url instead of absolute.

```
const cheerio=request("cheerio");
let url=prompt("Enter url?");

 fetch(url)
.then(function (response) {
  return response.text();
})
.then(function (html) {
  
    const $=cheerio.load(html);

    $("a").each((index,value) =>
    {

    let href=$(value).prop("href");
    
    if(typeof href!=="undefined")
    {
      console.log(href);
    }

    });

});
```

I used "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flame" url to test the code.İf there is another way of getting absolute urls of all links in a given url using cheerio I would like to know.

To make it clear,first I get an url from the user.I then fetch the url and extract its html document with cheerio.I need to get all links in that html document with absolute urls so that I can fetch them later.However the props value does not give absolute url for all of the links.Some href attributes give absolute value while others give relative.

Comment: Please, [edit] your question and provide a [mre], especially the HTML element you used. Is the `.each` iteration relevant and necessary to describe your problem? In jQuery, `$("<a href=\"https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flame\"></a>").prop("href")` returns `"https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flame"`.

Comment: Which part do you think needs editing? I tried to keep the code simple and easy to understand.Regarding the .each part I am trying to get all links in a given url so I need to cycle all of the <a> tags in the html and then get the href value for each of them.To make myself clear I get an url from the user,then I parse its html and extract it with cheerio.Now I have the html document of the site and I need to find all links in that html document.

Comment: Sounds like you are parsing an html document and expecting the relative links in that document to somehow automatically be converted to absolute urls for you.  You are going to have to perform that work yourself unless cheerio has that kind of functionality to perform those conversions for you as it downloads and parses the html document.

Comment: "Parse relative to absolute #567"
https://github.com/cheeriojs/cheerio/issues/567

Comment: I assumed it because https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5826581/is-the-a-href-property-always-returned-as-absolute in this links first answers second comment pointed that out but reading your answer I assume that it applies to browser but not cheerio right?İf that is the case I will mark it as answered.I will check the link you have given and write an answer accordingly.